# Match line not containing a pattern in BBEdit with Grep

Tags: grep, bbedit

I am having trouble finding the correct grep expression for not matching entire lines in BBEdit that do not contain a date, despite having found many "match ... not containing" topics on this on the web...

I have this text document:

```
Some Text
Some more text,even more text,2015-06-17,2015-06-20
A third line of text
Last line of text, 2015-06-17
```

This expression will select all lines that contain a date reference, in the form of 4 digits + "-" + 2 digits + "-" + 2 digits

```
^.*\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d.*$
```

I would like to match exactly the opposite, with the intention to remove all lines that do not contain a date reference. I have tried solutions like

```
^.*[^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d].*$
```

but with no success so far. Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BBEdit supports Perl-Style Pattern Extensions (see page 183 of the manual) [including negative lookaheads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/557612) `(?!...)`.

I believe this will do what you want:

```
^((?![\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d]).)*$
```

Comment: This certainly does the trick, but could use a bit more explanation.  I was trying to do something similar, knew I needed a negative lookahead, but created something like this: `^.*(?![^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d]).*$` until I found this page.  Obviously, I don't fully understand the use of the additional parenthesis and why `.*` isn't needed in the beginning.  If anyone can elaborate in the comments or by editing the answer, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I don't understand this either.

Answer (score 0):

One option

```
"[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}"
```

if you want to exclude the lines that dont have this match its easier to use *grep -v*

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion has made me simplify the expression into this: `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`. Still, I can't use the -v option since I am using BBEdit specific grep functionality in its search and replace window.